# How to Compile: Synergy on mac

Tags: macos, mouse, homebrew

I wanna use **Synergy** on my MAC and Windows. download synergy.zip file from https://github.com/synergy/synergy

and then I try to *compile* to **Xcode Project**

But I get the following error message

```
bash-3.2# ./hm.sh conf -g2
Mapping command: conf -> configure
Error: Arg missing: --mac-identity
```

I don't know why I cannot compile Synergy.

*Questions.*

1. What is **--mac-identity**?
2. How to typing command to terminal on my MAC?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to get this working on Yosemite with the following command:

```
./hm.sh conf -g2 --mac-sdk 10.10 --mac-identity Yosemite
```

Of course, this will only work given you have the dependencies. You can install them with the [Homebrew package manager](http://brew.sh).

```
brew install cmake qt
```

Additionally, you'll want to build it with:

```
./hm.sh build
```

And finally, to install it, you'll get the compiled results from the `bin` folder, i.e. `Synergy.app`.

Comment: You might consider submitting a formula or such for this. I think a lot of folks would like to just `brew install synergy` as the most recent version now since they've prevented binary downloading without pay.  I know a number of folks who are not too happy at the moment with the direction of the project.

Comment: Probably a good plan, hopefully I'll find some time in the coming weeks to take a look at putting that together.

Comment: unfortunately he's disabled the nightly builds again so our only option is that of compilation.

Comment: Used to work, but doesn't as of May 5th: The following build commands failed:
 CompileC build/src/lib/plugin/ns/synergy.build/Release/ns.build/Objects-normal/i386/SecureSocket.o src/lib/plugin/ns/SecureSocket.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

Comment: This is killing me right now. There are further errors too it seems. I tried:

`synergy-1.8.3-stable $./hm.sh conf -g2 --mac-sdk 10.12 --mac-identity Sierra`


`Error: Could not get revision, git error: 128`


When I run `synergy-1.8.3-stable $./hm.sh build` I get `The following build commands failed:
 CompileC build/src/lib/platform/synergy.build/Release/platform.build/Objects-normal/i386/OSXClipboard.o src/lib/platform/OSXClipboard.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)`

Comment: @anon58192932 I am facing the same build problem not the compilation problem. You have used qt4 for the compilation right?

Comment: @bizentass I just reverted an on older binary that I found precompiled. I'm running 1.8.4 or whatever the latest is on my linux box since it was part of the Ubuntu PPAs. And I'm using 1.5.3 or something close to it on my mac. 0 compatibility issues whatsoever. In short - give up on compiling on mac you don't need the latest version :)

Answer (score 6):

I have the similar problem on Yosemite. Perhaps you can find a compiled version [in the nightly builds](https://synergy-project.org/nightly/).

Comment: Interesting. I was hunting for those previously, but did not see them in the links that were floating around.  It appears that this has been updated semi-recently.  Thanks!

Comment: Apparently those are disabled again since he does not want us pulling precompiled versions.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how to compile it but if the reason you want to compile is to have it free, then you can just go to this link: [synergy-project.org/download/free/](http://synergy-project.org/download/free/)

It allows you to download previous versions of synergy (not the last one), kind of to keep the spirit of open source.

I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: 404 on the download link for mac right now. Probably transient. But it's 1.4.x versus 1.8.3? is the lats free version?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into that problem, and the solutions here helped me on my quest. I'm still running *Yosemite* but *El Capitan* is out.

The consequence of that is that **SDK has a different path**, since it now is able to compile for *El Capitan*.

```
sh ./hm.sh config -g2 --mac-sdk 10.11 --mac-identity Yosemite # My answer
```

Anytime a new OS is out, it would be logical to run

```
xcrun --show-sdk-path
```

to update the argument.

As for the answer to "what is mac-identity", it's a parameter to the compile script located at  ***ext/toolchain/commands1.py***, which uses it to codesign:

```
    err = os.system('codesign --deep -fs "' + self.macIdentity + '" Synergy.app')
```

somewhere along line 830.

BoldAsLove is correct that these lines must be commented out (or deleted)

```
#               if (NOT (OSX_TARGET_MAJOR EQUAL 10))
#                       message(FATAL_ERROR "Mac OS X target must be 10.x")
#               endif ()
```

Also, qmake was stored in

```
/opt/local/libexec/qt5-mac/bin/qmake
```

but this is probably a macports quirk.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and future-proof answer!

Answer (score 1):

To compile on OS X 10.10 Yosemite, comment out the following lines starting at line 171 in CMakeLists.txt

```
#               if (NOT (OSX_TARGET_MAJOR EQUAL 10))
#                       message(FATAL_ERROR "Mac OS X target must be 10.x")
#               endif ()

#               if (OSX_TARGET_MINOR LESS 6)
                        # <= 10.5: 32-bit Intel and PowerPC
#                       set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "ppc;i386"
#                               CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
#               else()
                        # >= 10.6: Intel only
                        set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "i386"
                                CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
#               endif()
```

Comment: I am getting a different error even after commenting out that code. `The following build commands failed:
 CompileC build/src/lib/platform/synergy.build/Release/platform.build/Objects-normal/i386/OSXClipboard.o src/lib/platform/OSXClipboard.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)`