# How to Compile: Synergy on mac (new toolchain from 2017)

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I know a question on that topic already exists ([How to Compile: Synergy on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923227/how-to-compile-synergy-on-mac)) but it looks like the old toolchain was deleted by a change on January 26 2017.

They use cmake now to handle the build but I was not successful on building it properly on MacOs Sierra (it complains about assert.h missing -.-). If I fix it by adding `/usr/include/` to the include paths the build then complains about not finding `CoreServices/CoreServices.h`

Reaching that point I think that I must be missing something vital to build it properly but what ?

Steps I followed:

```
git clone https://github.com/symless/synergy
cd synergy
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
# there it complains about not finding assert.h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT in the `cmake` command. This is from [Compiling · symless/synergy-core Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/symless/synergy-core/wiki/Compiling):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk \
      -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9 \
      -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 ..
```

You can leave the `10.9` for the target as it is, but change `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk` to match the actual path on your system if it's different.

Comment: it works thanks! that wiki entry was not there when I asked that question :)

Comment: though I'm on `10.14` I've set target to `10.9` as suggested; compilation fails with `src/lib/core/ToolApp.cpp:130:34: error: no member named 'internet' in 'Arch'`